# Android Studio change xml file appearance

Tags: android, android-studio

I must have accidentally pressed a keyboard shortcut and now a weird green color appears in the empty space of an xml file in Android Studio:

[image]

Any tips how to remove that green color? I've checked the appearance settings but can't seem to find that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

Ctrl + Enter on the empty space -> Un-inject Language/Reference

(seems that this option is enabled by pressing Ctrl + Enter and selecting the 'Inject language or reference' option)